# Lookup gives out random data

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I have a userform to input a Material Number. I then use a lookup to get the matching stock level, the consumption and the last goods receipt.

This works when I type in a correct Material Number.
If I type in a random number, which the macro normally should not match, it puts out random data. Like consumption of the last correct Material Number for example.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm1.Caption = "Eingabe"

Var1 = TextBox1.Value 'Msg Box wird als Variable festgelegt

    VBestand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Var1, Worksheets("Bestand").Range("A2:C4"), Worksheets("Bestand").Range("B2:B5")) 'VBestand wird als Variable für den Sverweis festegelegt. Es wird nach Var1 gesucht
    VVerbrauch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Var1, Worksheets("Verbrauch").Range("A2:C4"), Worksheets("Verbrauch").Range("B2:B5"))
    VWareneingang = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Var1, Worksheets("Wareneingang").Range("A2:C4"), Worksheets("Wareneingang").Range("B2:B5"))
    VReichweite = VBestand / VVerbrauch
    
Dim lZeile As Integer

    lZeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(lZeile, 2) = VBestand 'In der untersten Zelle wird der Bestand ausgegeben
    Cells(lZeile, 1) = Var1 'In der untersten Zelle wird das gesuchte Material ausgegeben
    Cells(lZeile, 3) = VVerbrauch 'In der untersten Zelle wird der Bestand ausgegeben
    Cells(lZeile, 4) = VReichweite
    Cells(lZeile, 5) = VWareneingang
Unload Me
VWareneingang = resetVWareneingang
End Sub
```

I thought that the data is just saved from the last check, that's why I tried "reset" in the end.

My goal is that if there is a wrong Material Number, which the macro cant find, it gives out a massage box and ends the macro.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English :D

Answer (score 0):

You using a Lookup (the excel worksheet function).  This function will return a the closest value in the lookup array if no exact match is found.
When writing formulas in Excel(You are using excel worksheet function in VBA) rather use an nested Index / Match formula to ensure exact match.

Also be careful using a vlookup - the data tables needs to be sorted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use VLookup rather than Lookup, and set the fourth parameter as `False` to specify an exact match required. The second parameter of VLookup is the whole table that you are referring to, with the values being looked for in the first column. The third parameter is the column within this to return a value from. Check the returned value for an error.

```
Dim MatchReturn As Variant
MatchReturn = Application.VLookup(Var1, Range("A1:E30"), 2, False)
If IsError(MatchReturn) Then MsgBox ("Eror") Else MsgBox (MatchReturn)
```

Here the table given is `A1:E30`, but the values are looked for in `A1:A30` (the first column) and the returned values are from the second column, i.e. `B1:B30`.